# Express a trigonometrical expression as an integral polynomial in $\alpha$ & $\beta$

Tags: trigonometry

How could we express this [image] as an integral polynomial in $\alpha$& $\beta$ ?

I tried a lot but cannot get any start .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

If $\tan^{-1}u=A;\tan A=u,\cos A=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$

$\csc^2\dfrac A2=\dfrac2{1-\cos A}$

If $\tan^{-1}v=B;\tan B=v,\cos B=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+v^2}}$

$\sec^2\dfrac B2=\dfrac2{1+\cos B}$

Formula used: $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y=2\cos^2y-1$

Comment: How you have written second step

Comment: $\cos 2x =1-2\sin^2x \Rightarrow \sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos x}{2}$. Now put $x=A/2$.